# PHP NuSOAP Pagination

Tags: php, pagination, nusoap

I've got the data from nusoap webservice and put it in the table. Here is the  code function:

```
`$filter='';
 $order='';
 $limit='10';
 $offset='';
 $result=$proxy->GetRecordset($token,$table,$filter,$order,$limit,$offset);
`
```

After parsing the json, here is the result:

[table with total data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4AHC.jpg)

Now the problem is I don't know how to split the data into pagination. The total data is 251 data (country ID with name). I change offset to 10 manually from the code and it give the result from 11-20.

I stuck with this code (don't know what to do):

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
}

$total_page=ceil($total_data/$limit);
$self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];    
echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
for ($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++){
echo "<li><a href=\"$self?tabel=$table&lihat=Lihat?page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

Here is the result:

[Table with link pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pWaw.jpg)

But when I click page number 2,3,...etc it still the same data. How I should do when I click the page number e.g 2 it will refresh the page and change the offset to 10 and so on. Please help. Thanks.